# How ascertain that loaded page triggering OnLoadEnd corresponds to HTML of LoadString?

Tags: delphi, chromium, onload-event

When I issue a

```
Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString(HTML,'code_url');
```

it appears that the `OnLoadEnd` event sometimes still loads the HTML of my previous `LoadString` (maybe several frames are being loaded separately).

I am using

```
if not frame.IsMain then
  Exit;
```

to make sure only the main frame is being considering in `OnLoadEnd`, but there are occasions in which a `CefGetBitmap` returns the bitmap of the previously loaded page (HTML).

My question: how do I know `OnLoadEnd` is triggered while the ChromiumFMX component is already displaying the correct page?

Comment: Yes, I have monitored the HttpStatusCode. It is always 0.

Comment: Indeed, it's just a string, not a URL. Right now I'm going to test adding a comment line to the HTML string, and intercept that in the OnLoadEnd. See if I can bind it in that fashion.

Comment: I will post the HTML content after the test, but it happens at different loads each time (I am sequentially loading many pages, to convert them to an image). And of course you can clean it up (a temporary draft or workplace section is actually not a bad idea for StackOverflow).

Comment: After digging and digging, I'm starting to think it has to do with CefGetBitmap(browser,PET_VIEW,bmp), which sometimes seems to return the previous page's bitmap...

Comment: That would be strange since the `browser` parameter passed to the `OnLoadEnd` always contains a new reference to `ICefBrowser` interface.

Comment: Tell me about it. I'm afraid I'm going to stumble upon something extremely stupid on my side and will be too ashamed to show myself for a month. But I'll be brave and report back.
Btw, I'm always using the same browser (on a form), so I suppose ICefBrowser remains constant?

Comment: No it's not *constant*. Each frame that is loaded has a new reference of `ICefBrowser` interface. So I meant that the content of the `browser` passed to that event should always be current, because you always get new *interface instance* (interface reference).

Comment: At the moment I've narrowed it down to the TChromiumFMX component sometimes not visually updating until the next Chromium.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString is issued. So sometimes the component keeps showing the previous HTML page, ignoring the last LoadString, then at the next LoadString shortly flashing the correct page before loading the next one. Have tried Application.ProcessMessages and Repaint to no avail.

Comment: Now tracked it down to sheer speed. If the subsequent HTML is too concise, too fast, then the OnLoadEnd will be triggered with the previous page still loaded. The correct page will only be loaded (shown) when OnLoadEnd is finished, without triggering another event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the HTML is very concise (small), it is loaded extremely rapidly, and the `OnLoadEnd` event is triggered before the ChromiumFMX component is updated.
To handle ChromiumFMX content, wait until the `OnLoadEnd` procedure has finished. This can be achieved, for instance, by waiting for it to complete in a loop.

```
procedure TfrmChromiumThumbnailing.ChromiumLoadEnd(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame;
  httpStatusCode: Integer; out Result: Boolean);
begin
  if (frame <> nil) and frame.IsMain then
    PageLoaded := True;
end;
```

In other code:

```
PageLoaded := False;
ChromiumFMX.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString(HTML,'code_url');
while not PageLoaded do
  Application.ProcessMessages;
<handle ChromiumFMX content>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you code this
ChromiumFMX.Browser.MainFrame.LoadString(HTML, 'code_url');

in the call back procedure TfrmChromiumThumbnailing.ChromiumLoadEnd(Sender: TObject;
  const browser: ICefBrowser; const frame: ICefFrame;
  httpStatusCode: Integer; out Result: Boolean);

frame.url will be 'code_url'